# Mathematical Induction step $2^n < n!$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, proof-explanation

I am trying to learn discrete mathematics on my own and have been reading Rosen's discrete math textbook, there is one step in his proof that I do not understand.

Where
$<2*k!$ becomes $(K + 1)K!$

he states that $2 < k + 1$ but how is he determining that?

I have attached an image of the proof for viewers to see exactly, it is the second last line of the inequalities.

[image: Rosen Description Snapshot]

Comment: $$2<k+1\iff k>1$$ right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that he has clearly mentioned  $k \ge 4$ in the last line of the inductive step. And also it must be kept in mind that the inequality holds only for  $k\ge 4$.

So $k+1 \ge  5 > 2$

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Why is  2 < (k + 1) used, is the statement 2 < k also valid by the inductive step? And how is it possible to replace the 2 with (k + 1)? Is it because if you do, the inequality still holds? Since 2 != equal (k + 1) but since 2 < (k + 1) it doesn't break the inequality

Comment: @user2076774 Yes, in response to your first and third questions.

Comment: So you could also say 2 < k but the choice to use 2 < k + 1 was made since it completed the proof?

Comment: @user2076774 Exactly. Thats the main reason.

Answer (score 1):

The basis step says, it is true for $k=4$. And then the inductive step assumes that it is valid for a $k$ with $k\geq 4$.
 It's quite easy to deduce $k+1 > 2$ then.

Answer (score 0):

You have to have a base case.  Note that your inequality is false until $n=4$, so you should say for all $n\ge 4, 2^n \lt n!$  You prove the $n=4$ case by computation.  Then assume you have proved it for $k$ where $k \ge 4$.  Since you have $k \ge 4$, you have $2 \lt k+1$